# Prove that the maximal normal Abelian subgroup $A$ of metabelian group is equal to $C_G$($A$).

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be finitely génerated metabelian group, then there existe maximal normal Abelian subgroup $A$ such that $C_G$($A$)=$A$. I want to prove that  $C_G$($A$)=$A$.

Comment: i want to prove $C_G$($A$)=$A$.

Comment: $A$ is maximal  normal abélien subgroup of métabelien group $G$